# viewing IE on linux problem

Tags: ubuntu-10.04

i am following the following steps from website:

http://www.tatanka.com.br/ies4linux/page/Installation:Ubuntu

but when i run the wget i get an error:

helloises@helloise:~$ sudo wget -q http://wine.budgetdedicated.com/apt/387EE263.gpg -O- | sudo apt-key add -
gpg: no valid OpenPGP data found.

i have no idea what this means?
can anyone help please?
thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's because the URL you are trying to download gives a 404 error. The key may have been moved to another location. Contact the one whose key you are trying to add.

Comment: thanks, cant i just remove the: sudo apt-key add -  part? i am working on a dev box...

Comment: No, the whole point of the command is to add a new key to the apt keyring so you can install software from a new repository. Only wgetting the key will not add it to the keyring.

Comment: thank you...dont quite understand all this yet..so the key being moved means it is not available at location: http://wine.budgetdedicated.com/apt/387EE263.gpg  anymore???